# password_compat password_verify not working

Tags: php, passwords, hashcode, password-encryption

I'm using the password_compat library in a php create admin/login feature. I was able to upload hash coded passwords for each user but when I pull the users information from the database and compare it with the password they entered into the login using password_verify it goes to the else statement and gives me an error. Here's my code...

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$entered_username = trim($_POST['username']);
$entered_password = trim($_POST['password']);

// Check database to see if username/password exist
$found_user = Users::get_user($entered_username);
// Creates/Add record to log.txt
//log_action('Login', "{$found_user->username} logged in.");

        if (password_verify($entered_password, $found_user->password)) {
// login successful
        redirect_to("index.php");
    } else {
        $message = "Username/password combination incorrect." . $found_user->password;
    } 


}
```

When it shows the error I had it show the password too - just to make sure the object attributes were being assigned and it was pulling the hashed password and it does.

[image]

I think I missed a small step, any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. The column length needs to be at least 60 for the hashed password. Basically it was running out of space.